# Swift: Strange Collision Behavior

Tags: swift, animation

I'm building a Breakout game (#cs193p) and I've got the beginnings of the general working set up: The bricks, ball, and paddle all draw as they should. The collisions sort of work as they should, except the collision boundaries appear to be sort of wrong. They're generally larger than the paths I've constructed them with, but not always.

I've set the elasticity of the ball to zero, so that it rests on the paddle, so that the discrepancy is clear. This screenshot shows the ball resting on the incorrect collision boundary of the paddle.

[image: Screenshot]

The bricks and the black area at the bottom respond a little differently. For the bricks, the ball seems to be colliding with the bottom row of bricks when it visually reaches the next row. I've got the bricks disappearing "correctly" so the collision is doubly confirmed by the bricks disappearing. The black area at the bottom (the space for panning to move the paddle) has a similar issue: the ball dips a little into this area before bouncing.

Here is, well, a bunch of code, because I don't know where the problem might lie.

From my `BreakoutBehavior` class (I'm leaving out the gravity section because it doesn't seem to be a part of the problem):

```
    let collider: UICollisionBehavior = {
    let collider = UICollisionBehavior()
    collider.translatesReferenceBoundsIntoBoundary = true
    return collider
}()

private let ballBehavior: UIDynamicItemBehavior = {
    let behavior = UIDynamicItemBehavior()
    behavior.allowsRotation = true
    behavior.elasticity = 1.25
    return behavior
}()

internal func addColliderBoundary(path: UIBezierPath, named name: String) {
    collider.removeBoundary(withIdentifier: name as NSCopying)
    collider.addBoundary(withIdentifier: name as NSCopying, for: path)
}

override init() {
    super.init()
    addChildBehavior(gravity)
    addChildBehavior(collider)
    addChildBehavior(ballBehavior)
}

internal func addItem (_ item: UIDynamicItem) {
    gravity.addItem(item)
    collider.addItem(item)
    ballBehavior.addItem(item)
}
```

And here's some code from my `BreakoutView` class:
I'm giving you the paddle as just one example of a boundary problem, rather than also giving the bricks and pan area, to be more efficient. So of course some of the variables I refer to won't be present in my excerpts. Note that I've left out some things like adding the behavior to the animator, but know that everything is indeed working, I'm just having these boundary problems.

```
    private var paddleSize: CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: brickSize.width * 3, height: brickSize.height)
}
private var paddleOrigin: CGPoint {
    let x = frame.midX - paddleSize.width / 2
    let y = panOrigin.y - paddleSize.height
    return CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
}

    private func addBallAndPaddle () {
    let paddleFrame = CGRect(origin: paddleOrigin, size: paddleSize)
    let paddleView = UIView(frame: paddleFrame)
    paddleView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    paddleView.layer.borderWidth = 0.25
    addSubview(paddleView)
    paddle = paddleView
    behavior.addColliderBoundary(path: UIBezierPath(rect: paddleFrame), named: Boundaries.paddle)

    let ballFrame = CGRect(origin: ballOrigin, size: ballSize)
    let ballView = UIView(frame: ballFrame)
    ballView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    ballView.layer.borderWidth = 0.25
    addSubview(ballView)
    behavior.addItem(ballView)
    ball = ballView
}

    private lazy var animator: UIDynamicAnimator = {
    let animator = UIDynamicAnimator(referenceView: self.superview!)
    animator.delegate = self
    return animator
}()

private lazy var behavior: BreakoutBehavior = {
    let behavior = BreakoutBehavior()
    behavior.collider.collisionDelegate = self
    return behavior
}()
```

And here's code from the BreakoutViewController. `configureGameView()` is called in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

```
    private func configureGameView () {
    gameView.frame = topView.frame // topView is the view in IB
    gameView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
    gameView.addViews() // adds bricks, ball, paddle, pan area
    firstTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    gameView.addGestureRecognizer(firstTap) // DOESN'T WORK
    if let panView = gameView.panner {
        panView.addGestureRecognizer(UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: gameView, action: #selector(gameView.movePaddle(_:))))
        panView.addGestureRecognizer(firstTap) // DOESN'T WORK
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is this just an experiment or is it an actual game? The reason I ask is that you would be much much better off using SpriteKit for something like this. UIKitDynamics is used for animating UI and stuff. Not really meant to be a game engine,

Comment: What is the frame of `BreakoutView`?

Comment: @Fogmeister - It is more of an experiment; I'm doing it as an assignment for Stanford's CS193P class on iTunesU. The assignment and preceding lessons are about Dynamic Animation and SpriteKit has not been introduced so I want to keep sprites out of it. Good question though!

Comment: @DaveWeston, I've dragged a generic view into my storyboard, set its constraints to the whole view (minus the top layout guide) and then added my BreakoutView (gameView) as a subview of that view (topView) with a frame identical to it (gameView.frame = topView.frame)
I'll add code for that to my orig. post.

Comment: UIKit Dynamics is not for this kind of thing. Really.

Comment: @matt, I'm pretty sure Jonathan realizes that UIKit Dynamics is not designed for this, but that doesn't mean it shouldn't be tried. He's learning. It seems to me he already did the hard part and now he just wants to tweak it. Also, I think trying to stretch an API beyond its capabilities is an excellent way to learn its limitations.

Comment: I think the problem is that you're initializing the `UIDynamicAnimator` with the superview. So, the superview's bounds are the coordinate space, but you're using frames in `BreakoutView`'s coordinate space to specify the boundaries. Can you try making `BoundaryView` itself the reference view for the animator?

Comment: @DaveWeston that was it!!! And thanks for being understanding, being a "Yes" rather than a "No." :)